Pinescript using unpublished library of my own
How to use tradingview my own unpublished library in my own script
I'm trying to use my own library which is not published; in my own script; i"m not a paid member either, or an expert; I'm just trying things here, need help

You need to publish it in order to use it. If you don't want to share it with others, you can publish it as private.
Read this to get more information.
